# Configuring Hadoop as multi-nodes cluster

Tags: hadoop

I installed Hadoop 2.4.1 on centos linux on VMware.
I should configure Hadoop' cluster as multi-node cluster.First, I do not know how should to build multi nodes on a Hadoop' cluster . second , How should I configure nodes on Hadoop' cluster? Please guide me step by step and in detail, especially in defining nodes.

Comment: Well, that's a pretty broad question. Maybe you should play with a preconffiged Hadoop environment to find out how it all hangs together. Check out hortonworks for instance. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are designing two Node cluster

Let suppose your nodes and their roles are as follows:

```
NN-host NameNode, DataNode  
DD-host DataNode1
```

Lets start with NameNode 192.168.3.171

and config the xml files
Then update hdfs-site.xml file pointing to our directories:

> $HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml

And paste the following between `<configuration>` tag:

```
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/user/hdfs/datanode</value>
        <description>DataNode directory</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/user/hdfs/namenode</value>
        <description>NameNode directory for namespace and transaction logs storage.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
```

Let Hadoop modules know, where NameNode is located:

> $HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

And paste the following between `<configuration>` tag:

```
     <property>
         <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
         <value>hdfs://NN-host:50000</value> 
         <description>NameNode URI</description>
     </property>
```

> $HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml

```
   <configuration>
 <property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>NN-host:50001</value>
 </property>

  <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

> $HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

Now we can format our NameNode by issuing:

> hdfs namenode -format

or

> hadoop namenode-format

Now we have to make sure, that our NN-host master node can log in passwordless to other nodes:

```
ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@NN-host 
ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@DD-host
```

And add your slaves (DataNodes) to slave file. In my case:

```
NN-host  
DD-host
```

Let's configure our slave DataNodes 192.168.3.44 Steps are the same for both of them:

Prepare and create directories:

Then update hdfs-site.xml file pointing to our directories:

```
$HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml
```

And paste the following between `<configuration>` tag:

```
     <property>
         <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
         <value>/home/user/hdfs/datanode</value>
         <description>DataNode directory</description>
     </property>
     <property>
         <name>dfs.replication</name>
         <value>2</value>
     </property>
     <property>
         <name>dfs.permissions</name>
         <value>false</value>
     </property>
     <property>
         <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
         <value>false</value>
     </property>
```

Let Hadoop modules know, where NameNode is located here:

> $HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

And paste the following between  tag:

```
 <property>
     <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
     <value>hdfs://NN-host:50000</value>
     <description>NameNode URI</description> 
 </property>
```

running datanodes can see in multi node cluster :

> DD-host:50075

TO see all aplications in UI

> NN-host:8088

Comment: Gave thanks for that answer. But my problem is in the design. In other words, how do I define multiple nodes in the cluster? I need to work on the issue of scalability in hadoop.

Comment: there is stable version hadoop-2.x.x which can solve scalability problems.And above answers is for designing multi node cluster.

Comment: And i am using hadoop-2.5.2 in multi node cluster.Its working fine.